# Autohotkey | How To Change Int To Double

Tags: autohotkey

I was wondering if there was a way to change the int value of an auto hot key script to a double, as I am trying to "fine tune" how fast the cursor moves and would like to use a decimal value. The only way I can think of being able to input a decimal value would be to use double, but I can not figure out how to change the int values to double(or if it is even possible).

Here is the code and thank you very much in advance!!

```
#NoEnv
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

; NRA
NRA := 1

; NR
~LButton::
while GetKeyState("LButton") & NRA
{
DllCall("mouse_event", uint, 1, int, 0, int, 1, uint, 0, int, 0)
Sleep, 15
DllCall("mouse_event", uint, 1, int, 0, int, 1, uint, 0, int, 0)
Sleep, 5
}
return

; keys
Insert::ExitApp
delete::suspend
```

I am trying to change the Y values shown below to be decimal points

```
DllCall("mouse_event", uint, 1, int, 0, int, Y, uint, 0, int, 0)
Sleep, 15
DllCall("mouse_event", uint, 1, int, 0, int, Y, uint, 0, int, 0)
```

I know that the higher I change that Y value, the faster it goes, but I was hoping to be able to put a value (like 1.5 or 2.7 as an example) into that Y postion.

Answer (score 0):

In AutoHotkey v1.1, floating-point literals are actually just strings
and they have a default precision of 6 decimals for floating-point output, which can be changed easily by SetFormat, Format(), Round(), SubStr(), Floor() to display them. [Source](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=2305).

If you are planning on doing larger precision Math you are going to need to use a [Math library](https://github.com/aviaryan/autohotkey-scripts/blob/master/Functions/Maths.ahk).

I'm really not sure about your code, since you never specified what variable or showed any math where you needed more precision? Did you leave something out?

Double:

```
NRA := 1

MsgBox % format("{1:0.15f}", NRA) ; Double precision
```

Based on your edit:

Unfortunately [mouse_event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260(v=vs.85).aspx) only excepts [DWORD](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/d/dword.htm) and will only accept an Integer value in the range 0 through 4,294,967,295.

Your only choice it seems is to increment by 1 for maximum control.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been a little more specific, the code that I am trying to change is the Y position for the DLL Call mouse events. I will edit the question real quick